# In PHP it possible to use microtime() inside another microtime()?

Tags: php, microtime

I have a loop with a number of functions

I want to check how long the entire loop runs, and also each of the functions within the loop

Is it possible to use a parent and many child microtime functions simultaneously?

```
$start = microtime(true);

foreach ($rows as $row) {

  if ($row == "a") {
     $start1 = microtime(true);
     // do function stuff
     $finish1 = microtime(true);
     echo("function 1 took", $finish1 - $start1, "seconds");
  }

  if ($row == "b") {
     $start2 = microtime(true);
     // do function stuff
     $finish2 = microtime(true);
     echo("function 2 took", $finish2 - $start2, "seconds");
  }
}

$finish = microtime(true);

echo("all functions took", $finish - $start, "seconds");
```

Comment: Try it and see ;) Also the subject is misleading as nowhere are you actually using microtime inside another microtime. PS: your example above is missing where you declare `$finish`.

Answer (score 1):

By the "parent" function, I assume you mean the `microtime` function call outside the foreach loop.

If that's the case, then yes, each time you call `microtime`, it will return the current timestamp of the execution of the script, regardless of previous calls to `microtime`.